# How to add multiple css gradient as a multiple background?

Tags: css

I want to make a button like this without using image by gradients as multiple background. is it possible?

[image]

using single element

```
<span class="customStyleSelectBox">Dummy Text</span>
```

**Try at jsfiddle here** http://jsfiddle.net/Awf6s/2/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can define multiple gradients comma-separated. E.g.:

```
.customStyleSelectBox {
    ...
    background: linear-gradient(#fff, #999) no-repeat border-box, linear-gradient(#eee, #777) no-repeat border-box;
    background-size: 98px 50px, 18px 50px;
    background-position: 0 0, 98px 0;
    background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;
}
```

Also see your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Awf6s/4/).