# Css multiple gradient

Tags: css, gradient

I want to style background of one element in CSS, something like this:

- color gradient from top to bottom with no any transparency,
- transparency gradient with single color from left to right: left and right with no transparency, and middle with 100% transparency
- Second gradient should be on higher layer than first. Both placed on 100% of element's area

Code:

```
div.panel div.panel-heading
{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e8e8e8 0%,#dbdbdb 50%,#cdcdcd 51%,#e0e0e0 100%),
    /* Here I want have got second gradient, with transparency, on higher layer */;
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you need to show the code you tried and say what your problem is to get some help.

Comment: You can use gradient generator http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253452/how-to-add-multiple-css-gradient-as-a-multiple-background

Comment: This is not duplicate of that, I want not have got two gradient on different location of element, but in the same location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with `:after` and `:before` :

```
.gradient{
    height:400px;
    background: #61fc32;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #61fc32 0%, #f43034 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#61fc32), color-stop(100%,#f43034));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #61fc32 0%,#f43034 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #61fc32 0%,#f43034 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #61fc32 0%,#f43034 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #61fc32 0%,#f43034 100%);
    position:relative;
}
.gradient:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(40,51,201,0) 0%, rgba(40,51,201,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(40,51,201,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(40,51,201,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(40,51,201,0) 0%,rgba(40,51,201,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(40,51,201,0) 0%,rgba(40,51,201,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(40,51,201,0) 0%,rgba(40,51,201,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(40,51,201,0) 0%,rgba(40,51,201,1) 100%);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ofpjgfxn/)