# Using multiple CSS gradients

Tags: css

I want to create a rainbow effect that fades using CSS gradients.

Vertically, I want the rainbow effect:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet);
```

Horizontally, I want the fading effect:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1,1,1,1), rgba(1,1,1,0));
```

My initial thought was to have two `div`s, the outer with the transparency, and the inner with the rainbow, but the transparency just got swallowed.  Then it occurred to me that `background` on the outer element is not what will make this work.  It'd need to be `filter` for that pattern to work.

So either I need to figure out how to make `filter` work with a gradient (possibly an SVG that I can stretch?), or I need to use a single `<div>` whose `background` somehow takes into account both linear gradients.  I'd prefer the latter, since it's much simpler.

Are either of these possible?

### Update

Looking at [How to add multiple css gradient as a multiple background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253452/how-to-add-multiple-css-gradient-as-a-multiple-background) makes it look like I should just be able to do:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1,1,1,1), rgba(1,1,1,0)), linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet);
```

This is getting me close, but the horizontal gradient isn't causing the vertical gradient to gain transparency; rather, it's causing it to go from black to fully visible.

```css
.rainbow {
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1,1,1,1), rgba(1,1,1,0)), linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet);
}
```

```html
<div class='rainbow'></div>
```

I've also noticed that in the first gradient, the first three values in `rgba()` don't matter--only the alpha does.  I don't know what to make of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add multiple css gradient as a multiple background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253452/how-to-add-multiple-css-gradient-as-a-multiple-background)

Comment: Possibly... I'm having troubles getting the transparency to work using that method.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I updated the OP with what happens when applying the answer from your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.rainbow {
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(1, 1, 1, 0)), linear-gradient(to bottom, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet);
}
```

```html
<div class='rainbow'></div>
```

Comment: You can co-relate your background priorities with gradient and it can simulate an opaque vision.

Comment: Ahh, my issue was that I'd thought `rgba()`'s first three parameters were floats between 0 and 1, rather than values between 0 and 255.  Thanks!  This works assuming the background is white.  In order to work on any background, there'd probably have to be some javascript involved.

Comment: Nope. Think that, your background is magenta, then you need to apply rgba code of magenta over there with last opacity set to whatever you want. It will give a soothing finish to your gradient without JS.

Comment: Yes, I mean that for it to work over any background, you'd have to figure out what the background color of the parent is.  It still doesn't work for an absolute div moving across a screen, displaying what's behind it--which is what I'm needing it to do--but I've changed my method anyway, using individual 1px divs.  This allows me to make the div wavy, rather than a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Out](http://jsfiddle.net/jdniki/Vj87c/)

Just less complications when you can use a [gradient generator](http://www.cssportal.com/css-gradient-generator/) for css backgrounds. Handy and easy to use. Some things are better left off lazy.

## rainbow {

```
background: red; /* not working, let's see some red */
background: -moz-linear-gradient( top ,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 15%,
    rgba(0, 255, 0, 1) 30%,
    rgba(0, 255, 255, 1) 50%,
    rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 65%,
    rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 80%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,  left top,  left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)), 
    color-stop(15%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)),
    color-stop(30%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)),
    color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)),
    color-stop(65%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)),
    color-stop(80%, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)),
    color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)));
}
```

Comment: you can use `opacity:0.3` for your transparency over the element

Comment: That will make the whole thing transparent.  I want it to have a gradient transparency: opaque on the left gradually becoming transparent on the right.

Comment: are you talking about animations?

Comment: No, not unless the animation is a single frame long and achieves what I want.  Run the code snippet in the post, and imagine, instead of turning to black, the rainbow becomes transparent.