# How can I put two different gradient properties

Tags: css, gradient

I need to create a gradient banner that have the image V.
So I have this part that give me the image :

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%);
```

And this part that give me the image /:

```
background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%);
```

So I tried with this:

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%),
linear-gradient(-45deg, #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%);
```

I expect the image V but instead of I have the only image .

What I'm wrong?

Thanks

Edit: I want this output. Is it possible?
http://s18.postimg.org/cx5y2jtgp/image.png

Comment: That's because you have two solid colored gradients overlapping one another. The top layer has to be transparent for the one behind to show through. Can you add an image of the expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple css gradient as a multiple background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253452/how-to-add-multiple-css-gradient-as-a-multiple-background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @Harry, the top layer overlaps the bottom one.

Making the top layer go to transparent instead of `#ff0000` solves it:

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,transparent 37%),
linear-gradient(-45deg, #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose to assign two elements within the banner to replicate the background like shown in this fiddle:

---

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kgescbd/)

HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner {
  width: 100%;
}

#left{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%)
}

#right{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%)
}
```

---

**EDIT:** You can also use absolute positioning to make sure your content within the banner won't be affected.

[Fiddle_2](https://jsfiddle.net/8kgescbd/1/)

---

HTML:

```
<div id="banner" align="center">
  <div id="left">
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  </div>
<img src='http://allspark.net/cypherswipe/yang-grey-alpha.png' height="200px">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner {
  width: 100%;
}

#left{
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;

  background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%);
}

#right{
  right:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  #0000ff 12%,#ffffff 25%,#ff0000 37%);
}
```

---

Hope it helped!

Cheers,